# Is there any example for how to use twitter-text-1.5.0.js?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I just get twitter-text-1.5.0 library.It uses to RTL the text block when user writes in RTL languages.But I don't know how to use it.

Is there any examples or does anybody know how can I use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This GitHub project explains how it works and how to use it. From what I can tell it will automatically convert the textarea to RTL when a couple of RTL unicode characters are typed into the textarea (Set how many ).

http://github.com/twitter/RTLtextarea

Comment: I want to have a `textarea` with twitter ability to rtl the text if the user uses rtl language

Comment: I changed the answer. Hopefully this helps.